# My sons DNA show who my possible father is. Paternal side

Tags: relationship-analysis, mitochondrial-dna

My biological father could be my step grandfather. He is dead and so are all his siblings.

Would my sons DNA show my paternal side?

I am a woman.

Answer (score 1):

No, your son's DNA has less information about *your* ancestry than your DNA: about half as much as yours and none of it is anything that is not in your DNA. .

Answer (score -1):

There would be evidence of the your paternal relations but it would be diluted by half with by his father's contribution.  If there are surviving relatives of your step grandfather there might be an indication of a family relationship but it would not be a strong pointer to the source of the commonality.